# Inno setup Windows Registry not catchable

Tags: file, copy, registry, inno-setup

:-)

I already did already a little bit programming in Inno setup, but now I think I am not able to see the forest for the trees. :-)
I want to copy some customization files in the section "Copyfiles" into the installation path of the files which is located in the registry. For this I call "GetInstalledPath" and want to get the registry information. BUt the message box in the Copyfiles section with input message "Test" is afterwards empty and also the files are not copied into the right place. I could swear it worked in an earlier version, probably I changed sth or is there sth to take care about it?

Thank you very much for having a look!

Best wishes and stay healthy!
JH

```
function GetInstallPath(Param: String): String;
begin
  if Param = 'File1' then
    Result := 'C:\Program Files\FolderFile1'
   else if Param = 'InstPath32' then
    begin
      if RegGetSubkeyNames(HKLM32, 'Software\Programname', RegKeys) then
        begin
          if RegQueryStringValue(HKLM32,'Software\Programname' + '\'+ 'Versionnumber'+ 'Paths','InstallDirectory', Program_PATH2) then
              Result := Program_PATH2
          else
        end
      end
   else if Param = 'InstPath64' then
    begin
      if RegGetSubkeyNames(HKLM64, 'Software\Programname', RegKeys) then
        begin
          if RegQueryStringValue(HKLM64,'Software\Programname' + '\'+ 'Versionnumber+ 'Paths','InstallDirectory', Program_PATH3) then
              Result := Program_PATH3
          else
          MsgBox('InstPath64 ' + Program_PATH3, mbInformation, MB_OK);
        end
      end
end;

procedure WaitUntilInstalled();
var
  I: integer;
  count: integer;
begin
    count := 0;
    I := 0
    while (NOT FileExists(ExpandConstant('{tmp}\filename.txt'))) AND (count<90) DO
      begin
        count := count + 1;
        Sleep(1000);
      end;
end;


procedure CopyFiles(Param: String) ;
var 
SrcDir: String;
DestDir: String;
ResultCode: Integer;
Command: String;
  begin
      if Param = 'Example32' then
        begin
          SrcDir := '{tmp}\Customization';
          DestDir := GetInstallPath('InstPath32');
          Exec('md',ExpandConstant(DestDir),'',SW_SHOW, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode);
          Command :=  '"' + ExpandConstant(SrcDir) + '" "' +  ExpandConstant(DestDir) + '"' + ' /y /E /I';
          Exec('xcopy', Command, '',SW_SHOW, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode);
        end
         else if Param = 'Example64' then
        begin
          SrcDir := '{tmp}\Customization';
          DestDir := GetInstallPath('InstPath64');
         MsgBox('Test' + DestDir, mbInformation, MB_OK)
          Exec('md',ExpandConstant(DestDir),'',SW_SHOW, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode);
          Command :=  '"' + ExpandConstant(SrcDir) + '" "' +  ExpandConstant(DestDir) + '"' + ' /y /E /I';
          Exec('xcopy', Command, '',SW_SHOW, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode);
        end
end;
```

Comment: Your code has far too many branches and we do not know anything about the registry keys in your system. Debug your code in Inno Setup IDE, to see where it goes wrong. If you need our help, we need [mcve].

Comment: Btw, do not hard-code `C:\Program Files`.

Comment: Hi Martin, thank you for your answer. What do you mean with too many branches? Where for example? I thought I would need each... How can I debug?

Comment: I mean that we cannot debug all your branches for you. + Debugging: See the "Run" menu in Inno Setup IDE.